# clojure - build condp from a vector of hashmap

Tags: clojure

I would like to build a dynamic condp from a hashmap.
I have the following structure:
[{ :value 50 :ret "value50" }
 { :value 100 :ret "value100 }]

I would like to put create the following condp dynamically:

```
(condp < n
50 "value50"
100 "value100"
"default")
```

Should i have to use a macro to create this expression?

Comment: If you do this with a macro, then the map will need to be a literal, and will not work with maps as data passed in. On the other hand, a function that operates on the hash map and gets the same answer condp would can use hash-maps that are not literals visible at compilation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A macro would generate the correct form for you.

```
(defmacro mycondp
  [pred expr coll]
  `(condp ~pred ~expr
     ~@(mapcat (juxt :value :ret) coll)
     "default"))
```

Example:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(mycondp < n [{:value 50 :ret "value50"}]))
;; => (clojure.core/condp < n 50 "value50" "default")
```

Comment: this only works with data literals, and as such is just condp with added noise `(let [data [{:value 50 :ret "value50"}]] (macroexpand-1 '(mycondp < n data)))` =>
`IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)`

Answer (score 3):

from `(doc condp)` =>

`...
 For each clause, (pred test-expr expr) is evaluated. If it returns logical true, the clause is a match.
...`

That means that on the average case you will have m/2 comparisons where m is the number of entries in your hash-map so you might find a better solution if performance matters in your scenario.

Anyway Here you have an alternative solution, I don't say it's more efficient, just a little bit easier to read for the average coder as myself

```
(def n 90)
(def clauses (hash-map 50 "value50", 100 "value100"))
(get clauses (first (filter #(< n %) (sort (keys clauses)))) "default")
```

Edited to ensure in order evaluation of clauses

Comment: upvoted, because you can actually use this with a hashmap that isn't a compile time literal

Comment: @noisesmith You need to use `array-map` or perhaps `sorted-map`, not `hash-map`, to preserve the order of the presented pairs. On my system, `(hash-map 50 "value50", 100 "value100")` => `{100 "value100", 50 "value50"}`

Comment: I was aware about the order @thumbnail, but from `condp` documentation and source code I cannot say that `condp` would care about order neither but it actually does care. Anyway the fix is trivial `(get clauses (first (filter #(< n %) (sort (keys clauses)))) "default")`

Comment: You are now assuming that the given order is insignificant. I agree that the documentation for `condp` is inconclusive: it needs mending; `cond`'s is clearer. I'm sure you'd agree that anything other than evaluating the tests in the order given would be a severe shock to a programmer in any dialect of lisp.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I just enjoy arguing :)